# How to get the shared file with Microsoft Graph？

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I want to share files from MS OneDrive to a user via MS graph API. And user can view my shared file directly through the link. I have read the Document of Creating a sharing Link for a DriveItem and use this API to create a sharing link for my sharing files.

I wonder how to implement with MS graph API? Any suggestion and tips are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I assume you want to get the share file by using MS Graph API.

Base on my test, We can create a shareLink for this this file.

Then we can use the following steps to get the file information by converting the shareLink.

1. Encoding the shareLink by using the following logic:

   ```
           1)First, use base64 encode the URL.
           2)Convert the base64 encoded result to unpadded base64url format by removing = characters from the end of the value, replacing / with _ and + with -.)
           3)Append u! to be beginning of the string.
   ```
2. If you want access the shared files, you can use the following API:

`GET /shares/{shareIdOrUrl}/driveItem`

The `shareIdOrUrl` parameter is the result in step1.

This API will return all the information about the shared file.

As an example, to encode a URL in C#:

```
string sharingUrl = "https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1231244193912!12&authKey=1201919!12921!1";
string base64Value = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sharingUrl));
string encodedUrl = "u!" + base64Value.TrimEnd('=').Replace('/','_').Replace('+','-');
```

For more detail, we can refer to [this document.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/shares_get)

Comment: Thank you very much, it's helpful for me